# socket connection refused: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I have been teaching myself python sockets module with the help of *sentdex*. When i attempted to run the code the were no errors. The code was:

```
`import socket
from _thread import *

host = 'localhost'
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print('Waiting for a connection.')
def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply = 'Server output: '+ data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()


while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
`
```

When I attempted to connect to it on my raspberry pi, it gave the error:
`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`
I tried modifying the host to a myriad of different options that I read in other question such as `host=''`, `host=127.0.0.1`, and `host=0.0.0.0`. All to no avail;however, it did make a connection when I tried `host='localhost'` on the computer running the script. When i attempted to ping it from my raspberry pi 3, it did nothing. At first, it appeared to be working, but after a while of no change, when I canceled it, the raspberry pi showed that no packages have been received. Please tell me what could be the problem. Could it be either syntactical or firewall-based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my error: I had been attempting to connect to the ip of my router, not the ip of my computer (on which I was running the socket server). Sorry to be a bother.